# Scroll не работает Python Selenium Appium

Tags: python, selenium, appium

Подскажите как сделать прокрутку(scroll) на андроид эмуляторе?

пробовал:

> driver.scroll(0, 2250)
>   скрипт отработал без ошибок но ничего не произошло

ещё пробовал:

> driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2250)")
>   выдаёт ошибку Method is not implemented

Comment: Думаю, что надо поменять местами числа.

Comment: Я уже пробовал,но нет

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему вот таким способом

```
driver.swipe(470, 1400, 460, 470, 400)
```

больше вообще ничего не помогало